# Static PDF file on rails app not showing on website upon deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-ec2, public, rails-5.1.6

I've added this line `<p><%= link_to 'Download My Resume', "resume.pdf", { :class=>"btn btn-default btn-lg" } %></p>` to my html.erb, the link works perfectly on my local server but when I deploy it to my aws server, the webpage cannot be opened.

error message in logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/resume.pdf"):
```

I'm using Rails 5.1.6. I've already set `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` I'm pretty perplexed on what's going on, would appreciate some help. I do not want to use any pdf gem.

Thanks!

Comment: but can you give more information about it? resume.pdf is what, an static file? do you want to create a pdf from the same view?

Comment: yes, it is just a static file.

Comment: do you have puma as the server? where is the file on the app, do you have config.serve_static_assets set to true? do you have nginx too or just the rails server?

Comment: I tried  config.serve_static_assets set to true, doesn't work.

Comment: the file is available on the server? are you sure is on the public folder? remember that the folder or the file can be in the gitignore

Comment: 100% sure is at the public folder. If not, it wouldn't have work on my local server too. I'm using rails 5.1.6, you sure that works for this version too?

Comment: But is on the public folder on your server?

Comment: Log in by ssh, and see if the file is there

Comment: I can't login with ssh. But I went into my aws elastic beanstalk to download my latest application version and it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have just puma as the server, be sure that you set

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

in your production.rb file.

But I recommend to use nginx to serve this type of files.

I made a simple test starting a server in production mode and the error I have when trying to go to a public file is that the secret_key_base isn't set for production environment. I added a value for that on environments/production.rb and it worked

```
config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

and of course, SECRET_KEY_BASE needs to have a value.

Comment: Manage to ssh in and saw the file is there. Also researched that config.serve_static_assets is deprecated, rails 5 is using config.public_file_server.enabled = true. Anyway, it still doesn't work for me !

Comment: you are right, updated. and added more comments with a real test.

Comment: thank you for your effort @xploshioon but my error message wasn't that, mine was ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/resume.pdf")

Comment: awesome that yours worked though, you mean you replaced the value with SECRET_KEY_BASE?

Comment: omg it worked suddenly! i didn't touch the code at all and it worked after a night of sleep ?!

Comment: Sometimes it happens